# How to design a fixed position panel in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Sorry about the basic question. I tried to find an answer on Google looking for expressions such as "unmoving jpanel java swing" or "static jpanel java swing" but could not find anything useful.

I'm trying to compose a screen with two components, an umoving (fixed position) JPanel at the bottom of the screen containing a few buttons and another JPanel which scrolls vertically and horizontally above it.

This construct is going to be fitted in an already existing application.

I could provide some code but I'm assuming the above description is enough to result in one or more suggestions on how to accomplish it overall.

Comment: Sound like you should use the `BorderLayout`, which is the default layout of a JFrame. You add a `JScrollPane` containing the panel you want to scroll to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Then you add the panel with the buttons to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: Thank you @camickr, that sounds like a good suggestion.

Comment: @camickr It worked! Thanks again! Feel free to provide an answer if you want, I'll be glad to accept it.